# MonkeyTalk Click on ActionBar home button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, monkeytalk

Is there a way how to click on action bar Home button (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)?

I tried

```
Label ${myHomeId} Tap
```

I just receive

> Completed Script Playback - OK

but nothing happens... the activity is supposed to get back to the home screen.

The same for clicking on Menu Settings is working:

```
Label menu_settings tap
```

Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be clicked using the ADB command:

```
adb shell input tap 100 100
```

MonkeyTalk script looks like this:

```
#tap_actionbar_home.mt
Vars * Define x y
System * Exec adb shell input tap ${x} ${y}
```

The it is call from another script using:

```
Script tap_actionbar_home.mt Run 100 100
```

The values 100 and 100 may differ of course.

Answer (score 0):

In new release of MonkeyTalk (v2.0.8) ActionBar overflow items is now supported. Update you project with new MonkeyTalk Android Agent and check, if this solves your problem.